# merge mixpanel notification with my existing gcm structure

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mixpanel

I am using mixpanel push notification with my existing gcm structure . How can I merge both into one. Currently it does not register my reg_id on mixpanel.

Code:

```
 mixpanel.getPeople().setPushRegistrationId(reg_id);
```

If I use the entire code as below I get 2 notifications. How can I get single notification and mixpanel survey working together?

Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name=“com.example.Mainactivity.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.Mainactivity.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />
```

I have added :

```
  mixpanel.registerSuperProperties(props);
 mixpanel.identify(id);
mixpanel.getPeople().identify(id);
 mixpanel.getPeople().setPushRegistrationId(reg_id);
 mixpanel.getPeople().initPushHandling(SENDER_ID);
```

in my GcmBroadcastReceiver I have added:

```
if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("mp_message")) {
               String mp_message=intent.getExtras().getString("mp_message");
}
```

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="yourpackage.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.javapapers.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="yourpackage.notification.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

Comment: it will work for all notifications dont use GCMReceiver

Comment: @jason were you able to solve this problem? I am having the same issue currently.